# bootstrap input-group-btn ignores height 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Odd styling problem - Im trying to get the height of the '.input-group-btn' in bootstrap to fit the height of the parent container 'input-group'. This will run alongside the whole height of the select box next to it.

Simple problem, just cant seem to get the desired outcome it only sets 'px' based fixed values and ignores %...i need to set this to 100% height...how?

```
 <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="input-group add-on col-xs-2">
           <div class="input-group-btn">
                       <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Container Size" data-content="mg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group container-select">
                 <select id="hazards" multiple="multiple" name="hcode">
                       <option>None</option>
                       <option>1</option>
                       <option>2</option>
                       <option>3</option>     
                  </select>
             </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle With Me](http://jsfiddle.net/dzn7orxx/5/)

Comment: the `btn` class as padding top of 6px in it, this is part of your problem. ofcourse you dont remove that value from the `btn` class. but you can override the padding for that element

Comment: This does not solve it, still not filling parent    `.input-group-btn > .btn{
  height:100%;
   padding: 0 !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You had some excess vertical padding that was preventing it from being `100%` of the parents height.

Use this CSS instead,

```
.input-group-btn > .btn{
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0 20px;
   margin: 0;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/MaPGMz)

Here is the proper bootstrap way of formatting a `<select>`group with a button.

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
   <div class="input-group add-on col-xs-2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Container Size" data-content="mg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
      </span>
      <select id="hazards" name="code" class="selectpicker form-control">
         <option>none</option>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
         <option>4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

[NEW CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/PPyaGO/)

Comment: This does not solve the issue....the button is not the same height of the parent or select box?

Comment: Your ``<select></select>`` is not formatted correctly for bootstrap so it's not going to align right with the left. As a matter of fact a lot of your form is not.

Comment: Im using a seperate multi-select plugin for the 'select', this will have similar box style output as the standard non-bootstrap one.

Comment: then I would custom syle it all, when you start mixing bootstrap input fields and forms with non bootstrap options it gets really messy as you can see

Comment: I thought setting a button to 100% would be simple...sigh

Comment: it normally is but since bootstrap is a css framework they have a bunch of custom css, especially for form groups.

Comment: just to make sure its not the 'select box' i removed it and set the container to a fixed height...[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dzn7orxx/18/) Still same issue cant set 100% just fixed values

Comment: it's something with ``input-group-btn`` that doesn't want to align correctly with a non bootstrap element.